# Font Rendering Issue in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, cross-browser

I am seeing an issue with a site I am developing where the content regions of the page are showing random artifacts with font rendering.  The pages are using Google Font 'Source Sans Pro' and there are no additional tags other that p-tags in the screenshot below.  It looks like it is using the fallback sans-serif on parts of the page and the appropriate font in others.

[image]

I've also noticed if I toggle the font-family CSS attribute in the console on and off it remedies the appearance... Additionally if I refresh the page (instead of using the on-site navigation) it also seems to render properly.  I've not been able to replicate this on another machine with the latest version of Chrome, but it is consistent across my development and test environments. The only extensions I am using are Disconnect, AdBlock, PageSpeed Insights, an RSS reader, and Javascript Quickswithcer... All other browsers appear to behave as expected.

**CSS used:**

```
body,*{font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif}
```

Any ideas as to why the latest version of Chrome for Windows may be getting presented this way?

Comment: where is your reduced example? cut out all but one paragraph where things go wrong, look at the markup in it - is there an inline-element with different styling? Also, as CSS tip, don't set the font with `*`, it'll almost never do what you think it'll do. CSS is already "cascading" so without an override, fonts set for `body` will be inherited by everything inside of it unless there's CSS to override that: open your browser developer console, find the overrides (or even just right click on the text that 'looks wrong', hit inspect element, see what's going on).

Comment: At the moment this site is only available internally and not been published--there are no inline elements with styling.  The example in the screenshot are just 4 <p> tags one after another.

The only style for font-family showing in the console is the appropriate one shown above in my original post.

Thanks for the selector tip, I'll remove the *.

Comment: that doesn't matter: we don't want the entire site, it's not the entire site that's having a problem, it's bits of text, so your problem should reproducible as a jsbin or the like (it's just some HTML and CSS), so... reduce it (you might find the problem yourself while reducing, **always** reduce before asking) and then post that?

Comment: As a matter of fact, removing the * selector from that rule appears to have made all the difference!

Comment: I've recreated the core of what I was doing in a JSBin and do not see the same behavior occuring, but your recommendation did fix it in my environment. https://jsbin.com/cerifajife/edit?html,output

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too soon--still seems to be an issue.  I think just closing my browser and re-opening it remedied the issue temporarily.

Comment: try as I might I can't reproduce that visual effect on my end. are you running any extensions/add-ons or customizations?

Comment: Just those mentioned in the original post as far as browser extensions.  When the site goes live I will post the URL to it in the event that I am overlooking something.

Comment: Heh, re-installing Chrome fixed the issue for me across all environments.  Perhaps I should've started with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I came across a similar issue. I was able to fix it by overriding the CSS `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` set on the body tag by a CSS framework I was using like so:

```
body { text-rendering: auto; }
```

Note: In the interest of trying to track the bug down, my version of Chrome is 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) on OSX El Capitan. A coworker told me about the issue and I had to switch to incognito mode before I started seeing the issue.

Comment: Try to phrase this more as an answer than as a "me too" comment on sharing this issue.  You can do this by clarifying **how** to override it with `text-rendering: auto` (in an example that makes it clear you're talking about CSS).  Put your guess about it being a bug at the bottom (or better yet, remove it unless you can actually find and link to the bug – extra points for actually logging the bug and linking it here.)